# Don't select an habtm field in a find

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.6

I am here trying to improve one of my select.
My model is as follows:

```
Network
--->hasMany Esx
--->hasAndBelongToMany Environment
```

A network might have 0 Esx and/or 0 environments

So here I want to select some network information and the Esx section, but not the environment information.

```
  $this->Network->find('all',array(
          'conditions'=>array(
              'Network.plateform'=>IAAS,
              'Network.active'=>true),
          'fields'=>array(
              'Network.id',
              'Network.name')
     ));
```

So, I can't use fields to only select the vlan field
I can't lower recursive to remove environment because it would also remove Esx
I found on SO an other question that suggest to use $this->Network->schema() and remove the unwanted fields, but it doesn't return the hm and habtm structure.

In short, how can I transform the result of this query from this

```
0 => array(
    'Network' => array(
          'id' => '38',
          'name' => 'HP_LOW'),
    'Esx' => array(...),
    'Environment' => array(...)
 )...
```

To this

```
 0 => array(
      'Network' => array(
        'id' => '38',
        'name' => 'HP_LOW'),
      'Esx' => array(...)
     )...
```

The purpose is not to just unset the Environment field, but to not select it in order to improve database perfomance.

Thank you!
Ps: Im' workin with cakephp 2.6.2

Comment: did you try containable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use containable**

see the manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable)

in your Model you have to enable the Containable Behavior

```
class Networkextends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

then in the controller you can do

```
$this->Network->find('all',array(
  'conditions'=>array(
      'Network.plateform'=>IAAS,
      'Network.active'=>true),
  'fields'=>array(
      'Network.id',
      'Network.name'),
  'contain'=>array(
      'Esx')
 ));
```

Comment: Damn, I saw and try the 'contain', but I missed the actas in the mode...
Thank you!